# how to read a numerical result from f: close ()

Tags: lua, exit-code

I'm a terrible beginner:

```
f = io.popen("ping -c 2 -t 5 192.168.0.1")
l = f:read("*a")
f:close()       
if f==0 then print ("active")
else print ("off")
end
```

[image]

Comment: Is your desired outcome for it to print `active`? How are you printing that `{true, "exit", 0}` table? What variable is it in? If that is the zero you want to evaluate for, you just need to evaluate for `table[3]` as 0 is in the 3rd position.d

Comment: I use interactive reascript (reaper audio)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more detail as to what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far. You may edit your question according to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have the highest chance to get it answered and help this community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local f = io.popen("ping -c 2 -t 5 192.168.0.1")
local l = f:read("*a")
f = f:close()
if f then print ("active") else print ("off") end
```

Comment: @Crist - Remove all `local` and try again.

Comment: Yesss!!!   perfect ,  thank you so much.    f = f:close() it's what was missing.      ‍♂️